# SmoothState.js does not work together with custom written jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, content-management-system

I'm working on a website, it is made by drupal 7 and I am trying to add SmoothState.js to benefit from ajax and awesome animations.
The positive thing is that SmoothState.js works perfectly, all the animations everything.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the SmoothState work together with my previously written jQuery snippets.

In a nutshell I have made a block of menu--submenu--sub-submenu, and animated the dropdown with jQuery's .click(function() {}). After integrating SmoothState either smoothstate doesnt work if the jQuery snippet is working or if I comment the snippet out smoothstate works perfectly.

this is the snippet of jQuery

```js
$(".menu li").click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("> ul", this).slideToggle("fast").parent("li").toggleClass("arrowChange");
});
```

P.S. - I have another jQuery code working perfectly without any interruptions which adds or removes class on scroll. Btw, Im a beginner with jquery.

Comment: Anyone? fishing for people who have encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you need to make sure that your custom jquery is included properly. You'll need to read up on [Drupal behavior attachment](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors), but basically, make sure that your script is encapsulated in something that looks like this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

Then in the functions js that you use to call smoothState, make sure you invoke Drupal.attachBehaviors(); and it will run your custom JS, along with that of any other modules making use of behavior attachment.

So include something like this in your smoothState call:

```
onAfter: function() {
    Drupal.attachBehaviors();
}
```